# asp.net caching related to available resource?

Tags: c#, caching, datatable

I am caching a fairly large datatable into the application cache using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(GlobalVars.Current.applicationID + "_" + cacheName, itemToCache, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(240));
```

As you can see, it should stay in the cache for 4 hours, however we are seeing strange results:

On a site with low CPU & low RAM usage (say 0-150 users) we receive no errors.

On a site with high CPU and low RAM usage (CPU ~90%, 300 - 600 users), we get the following error every 20-60mins:

```
    Cannot find column EditorOrder.

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column EditorOrder.
   at System.Data.DataTable.ParseSortString(String sortString)
   at System.Data.DataView.set_Sort(String value)
   at delima_v1._01.templates.results.editors_picks.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

EditorOrder is a column that is added manually to the datatable once the results have been taken from SQL. So i'm unsure if the column is somehow being removed or the entire cache is being lost, the error seems to indicate it's the column being lost. As I said, it only seems to be under high loads so unsure as to whether IIS/Windows have any effect....

Site is running ASP.NET 4.0 in 64bit AppPool

Many thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: Just a quickie, you are checking that the DataTable is saved back in Cache after you add the column?

Comment: I'd suggest adding a callback for when the cache item is removed so you can determine whether that's the problem. It's one of the overloads for the `Insert` method.

Comment: Hi, yes, the datatable is definitely saved into the cache as the site would error or be exceptionally slow as it would have to return the data each time